# onActivityResult() when the app gets killed in background

Tags: android, android-intent, background, android-activity, kill

While i am running an application the activity gets killed due to memory issue.

I am calling startActivityForResult() method in my activity to start camera. It is showing unusual behavior, when the calling activity gets killed in background. Some times the intent returns to onActivityResult() with result after entering onRestoreInstance(). But in some other case it is not entering onActivityResult() after entering onRestoreInstance().

Could any one please explain me why this behavior happens.

Comment: print stack trace so that other can understand what is your exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your new activity using this code

```
        Intent i = new Intent(this, DatabaseEditor.class);
        //You may pass value on another activity
        i.putExtra("xCoordinate", String.valueOf(o));
        i.putExtra("yCoordinate", String.valueOf(p));
        i.putExtra("scale", scaleTest);

        startActivity(i);
```

then override onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            // Write your code on result ok return
        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Write your code on no result return
        }
    }
}
```

On your new activity you can get your passed value using this code

```
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (b != null) {
        editTextX.setText(String.valueOf(b.getString("xCoordinate")));
        editTextY.setText(String.valueOf(b.getString("yCoordinate")));
        editTextScale.setText(Float.toString(b.getFloat("scale")));
    }
```

if you want to go back to previous activity simply call finish();

```
 //if you want to pass a value from this activity to you mainActivity use this  
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent(
        "com.example.activity.MainActivity");
            returnIntent.putExtra("id", streetID.intValue());
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
```

Since you set the used setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent); then your code for

```
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            // Write your code on result ok return
        }
```

gets executed.. Cheers!!! :D

Comment: I am calling intent to open up camera to capture video.

Comment: in depends on the result you are passing.... make sure you passed a value before your second intent gets terminated setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);

Comment: The case is, activityOnResult is not being called in the caller activity.

Comment: could you post in your code so that we could analyze it... just the onactivityresult and your second activity....